# Twitter comment ElementNotInteractableException selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I was using selenium to automate twitter comments but when I'm unable to send keys to the elements  [Image of the element to interact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVPuL.png)

Console error => `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block pu blic-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"> is not reachable by keyboard`

I've tried using class name.

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "public-DraftStyleDefault-block").send_keys("Hello")
```

XPATH for `data-testid`

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="tweetTextarea_0"]')
```

Tried clicking the element before sending keys

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "public-DraftStyleDefault-block").click()
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "public-DraftStyleDefault-block").send_keys("Hello")
```

Actionchains didn't worked as well

```
action.send_keys("Hello")
```

[Expected result was for the keys to be sent in the text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guqjU.png)

Comment: I think the error is because the element of the page is changing, try to refind the element.

Answer (score 0):

The `ElementNotInteractableException` in Selenium is thrown when an element is present on the DOM tree but is not in a state that can be interacted with. Try this one it might work for you.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath_of_element_to_be_invisible")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath_element_to_be_clicked").click()
```